# HandsOnTable context menu options repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, handsontable

I am trying to use HandsOnTable in a web page designed using SAPUI5. I have an issue with the display of Context Menu. The options in the context menu repeat after the last option in the menu. I have included the code below. Please help me resolve the issue.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('sheetContainer');

var settingsHOT = {
  data: data,
  autoWrapRow: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  comments: false,
  contextMenu: {
    items: {
      "copy": {},
      "paste": {},
      "row_above": {},
      "row_below": {},
      "remove_row": {},
      "undo": {},
      "redo": {},
      "make_read_only": {},
      "alignment": {}
    }
  },
  contextMenuCopyPaste: {
    swfPath: "resources/ZeroClipboard.swf"
  },
  columns: [{}, {}, {}, {
    editor: 'select',
    selectOptions: ["Yes", "No", "Yes with exemptions"]
  }, {}, {
    renderer: 'html'
  }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
  colWidths: [120, 100, 200, 150, 250, 250, 100, 250, 250, 250, 125],
  fixedColumnsLeft: 1,
  fixedRowsTop: 0,
  minRows: 1000,
  minCols: 26,
  maxRows: 10000,
  maxCols: 1000,
  minSpareRows: 5,
  manualColumnResize: true,
  manualRowResize: true,
  manualColumnMove: true,
  manualRowMove: true,
  mergeCells: false,
  persistentState: true,
  rowHeaders: true,
  removeRowPlugin: true,
  startRows: 5,
  startCols: 5,
  stretchH: 'none',
  search: true,
  wrodWrap: true
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by "repeat"? can you show us a screen capture?

Comment: By repeat I mean, Copy, Paste, Insert Row Above, Insert Row Below, Alignment etc., options are displayed in the context menu. After the last menu option i.e., Alignment, Copy, Paste, insert... all these options reappear below Alignment option.

Comment: that was an old bug. what version are you using?